# How can I test different app configurations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an model whose behavior should change slightly based on a configuration file. The configuration file, in theory, will be altered for each installation of the app for my clients. So how can I test for these changes?

For example...

```
# in app/models/person.rb

before_save automatically_make_person_contributer if Rails.configuration.x.people['are_contributers_by_default']



# in test/models/person_test.rb

test "auto-assigns role if it should" do
  # this next line doesn't actually work when the Person#before_save runs...
  Rails.configuration.x.people['are_contributers_by_default'] = true
end

test "won't auto assign a role if it shouldn't" do
  # this next line doesn't actually work when the Person#before_save runs...
  Rails.configuration.x.people['are_contributers_by_default'] = false
end
```

It doesn't make sense for these to be stored in the database, because they are one time configurations, but I need to make sure my app behaves under all the possible configurations in all environments.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the way to make this work is to rewrite the `Person` class so that `automatically_make_person_contributer` actually performs the evaluation of `Rails.configuration.x.people['are_contributers_by_default']`. This makes my tests happy and technically doesn't change the way the app works:

```
# in app/models/person.rb

before_save :automatically_make_person_contributer 

private
  def automatically_make_person_contributer
    if Rails.configuration.x.people['are_contributers_by_default']
      # do the actual work here
    end
  end
```

However, this means that a value that is going to remain the same for the lifetime of the app's process will be checked every time a `Person` is created, instead of checked only once at the creation of the `Person` class.

In my particular case, this tradeoff is fine, but others may want the actual answer to my question.